# Creating a pool of locks in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, mutex

I would like to use exactly one of a set of resources from a multi-threaded C# application. These resources are not thread-safe, so some lock or mutex must be for them. How should I do it?

I would like to get something like the following pseudo code:

```cs
lockAny([obj1, obj2, obj3]) {
    achievedLock = getAchievedLock(); // returns e. g. obj2
    myResource = getResourceForLock(achievedLock); // some function written by me, looks up the resource belonging to the particular lock
    myResource.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: why not use `ObjectPool`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/objectpool?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Encapsulate thread-safety within each object (or a generic wrapper around them) and all that's left is the design for which to grab next.  Despite the tag, stay away from `Mutex` (unless that's just short for mutual exclusion) as it's heavyweight for interprocess.  I'd probably go with Monitor.Enter/TryEnter (lock keyword) but I'd personally do it all wait-free user mode.  Not recommended unless you really know what you're doing.  Simplest collection that fits is a FILO queue, but maybe not ideal if you have large variation in how long you hold locks.

Comment: So you want an exclusive access to *any* one resource? Perhaps you could add the resources to a blocking collection, take objects and re-add them when your done?

Comment: @DanielA.White I've never heard of this before, but I like it, seems I can do it with it

Comment: @Zer0 that's almost like object pooling, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with some sort of pooling. A pool object can attempt to ensure that only 1 thing has a reference at a time (but .NET can't guarantee that like Rust).

.NET has recently added [`Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). You can configure how it creates the items. [Some examples here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/objectpool?view=aspnetcore-6.0)